# Instagram plugin for PhoneGap/Cordova not return to application back (from instagram app to phonegap app) after sharing

Tags: cordova, instagram

I have implement below plugin for instagram,

https://github.com/vstirbu/InstagramPlugin

It open popup to share on instagram using instagram app installed in device after completing all the required steps to share control not back (from instagram to phonegap app).

Please help me on same if anyone have implemented this type of functionality in phonegap app.

Answer (score 0):

Once you redirect to instagram app you can not back to your app. you have to open your app again

Comment: I knew that but I looks for if anyone has the solution to redirect control back to phonegap app.